# Chrome 74 breaks work of a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that downloads Facebook messages to the computer. After the latest update of Chrome (v.74) it stopped working.

I have created a test extension that will help you understand what has happened.
So you can either download it from here: [test extension](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15mOEhCZv1_x2SIo1etn638eeBDkvfhCv) or create it from scratch by using the code I provide below.

**manifest.json**

```
{"name": "TEST",
"description": "TEST CHROME 74 BROKEN RESPONSE HEADERS",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,    
"permissions": [        
    "https://*.facebook.com/",
    "activeTab",
    "cookies",
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "storage",  
    "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" 
],

"web_accessible_resources": [       

],
"background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(details)
{
    if ((details.url.indexOf('https://www.facebook.com/api/graphql/') !== -1 ||
         details.url.indexOf('https://www.messenger.com/api/graphql/') !== -1 ||
    details.url.indexOf('https://www.facebook.com/api/graphqlbatch/') !== -1 ||
         details.url.indexOf('https://www.messenger.com/api/graphqlbatch/') !== -1)            
        && (details.requestBody.raw || details.requestBody.formData)) {

    var match;

    if (details.requestBody.raw) {
        var decoded = decodeURIComponent(new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes));
        match = decoded.match(/"(threadFBID|messageThreadID)":"(\d+?)"/);        
    }

    if (details.requestBody.formData) {
        match = details.requestBody.formData.variables[0].match(/"(threadFBID|messageThreadID)":"(\d+?)"/);
    }


    if (match) {
        chrome.storage.local.set({ 'chatID': match[2] }, function(){                               
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {
               chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"}, function(){                        
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { file: "js/dateOptions.js" }, function() {                   
                    }); 

                });    
            });
        });
    }
}

},
{urls: ["https://www.facebook.com/*", "https://www.messenger.com/*"]},
['requestBody']);
```

**dateOptions.js**

```
var load_data = function(token, id) {  

   var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/api/graphqlbatch/';    
   var docId =  '1699057486820841';         
   var dataString = '__user=' + id + '&__a=1&fb_dtsg=' + token;


   dataString +=
   '&queries=%7B%22'
   + 'o0' + '%22%3A%7B%22'  
   + 'doc_id' + '%22%3A%22' + docId + '%22%2C%22'
   + 'query_params' + '%22%3A%7B%22' 
   + 'limit' + '%22%3A' + 50 + '%2C%22' 
   + 'before%22%3A' + null + '%2C%22'
   + 'tags%22%3A%5B%22' + 'INBOX' + '%22%5D%7D%7D%7D';


   $.ajax({                    
       type: 'POST',
       url: url,
       data: dataString,
       dataType: "json",   

       success: function(data){

       },
       error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

           chrome.storage.local.set({
               'data': XMLHttpRequest.responseText
           });
       }                   
   });   };



var set_id_and_token = function(cb) {
   var scr = document.querySelectorAll("script");
   var myIdSet = false, tokenSet = false;
   // set FB token and owner's id
   for (var i = 0; i < scr.length; i++) {    

       var token = scr[i].textContent.match(/\"token\"\:\"(.*?)\"/);
       if (token) {  
           token = token[1];
           tokenSet = true;
       }

       var id = scr[i].textContent.match(/\"USER_ID\"\:\"(.*?)\"/);
       if (id) {
           id = id[1];
           myIdSet = true;
       }

       if (myIdSet && tokenSet) break;
   }

   cb(token, id);                                                                           
}



chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) { 

   set_id_and_token(function(token, id){
       load_data(token, id);
   });    });
```

You will also need a **jquery-3.1.1.min.js** file to get AJAX requests running.

### **So the steps to reproduce the issue:**

**1.** Add the test extension to your Chrome browser.

**2.** Go to https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/ (you have to be logged in of course)

**3.** Choose any chat in the Inbox.

**4.** Open the popup window of the extension.

Now depending on the version of Chrome you will get one of the two outputs.

If you have version 74 and higher:

[image]

If you have version before 74:

[image]

That is, before the latest update the extension could get the necessary information from Facebook servers.

### What I have found so far.

I looked into the requests sent by the extension on these two different versions of Chrome and found the following differences.

**In Request headers - difference in origin**

Version 74+:

[image]

Version below 74:

[image]

**In Response headers - difference in access-control headers and CSP**

Version 74+:

[image]

Version below 74:

[image]

If anyone can share their ideas on how this can be fixed, I will be grateful.

Comment: Seems like a breaking change in the extensions API. By the looks of it v. 73 introduced this: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches. Maybe try some of the proposed workarounds/solutions there?

Comment: @Vasil Dininski Thanks, I will have a look. You say though that it started from v.73. But v.73 still worked fine.

Comment: Could be https://crbug.com/944704 which is a work in progress, AFAICT.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, that seems to be my case, thanks. So it's only to wait for a fix then..

Answer (score 1):

So while Chrome is working on the bug fix, I have come up with the following solution of overriding the **'origin'** request header.

The following code should be put in the **background.js**:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
function(details) {
    //details holds all request information. 
    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
        //Find and change the particular header.
        if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'Origin') {

            details.requestHeaders[i].value ="https://www.facebook.com";
            break;
        }
    }
    return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders };
},
{urls: ['<all_urls>']},
['blocking', 'requestHeaders']);
```